# Is it possible to change the cmdline of a running process (to more easily identify it in top, for example)?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, process, top

I run a number of linux servers with VMware Server 2. When their response time is not so hot or the load average goes up, I open up `top` to see what's going on, or for our production servers I have `top` open all day long. The issue is, the cmdline of `vmware-vmx` processes is *really* long, for example:

```
/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-vmx -# product=2;name=VMware Server;version=2.0.2;buildnumber=203138;licensename=VMware GSX Server for Linux;licenseversion=3.0 build-203138; -@ pipe=/tmp/vmhsdaemon-0/vmxaf9a31943e9065f0;readyEvent=55 /var/lib/vmware/Virtual Machines/Kyle.vmwarevm/Kyle.vmx
```

So in `top` all I see is:

```
 4135 root      20   0  593m 324m 289m S   21  4.2   3038:04 /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-vmx -# product=2;name=VMware Server;
 4106 root      10 -10  997m 399m 346m S    9  5.1   1135:25 /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-vmx -# product=2;name=VMware Server;
 4074 root      20   0  833m 110m  97m S    2  1.4 722:19.38 /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-vmx -# product=2;name=VMware Server;
```

In VMWare Server 1, each VM would run as it's own user so I could easily tell which one was which. Not so with VMWare Server 2. In lieu of buying a really wide monitor or a triple monitor setup, is there any way I can alter the cmdline of these running processes so I can easily identify which one's which? I know the processes can alter the cmdline of themselves... and I can read (but not write to) `/proc/nnn/cmdline`...

Is there any way (as root) to alter the cmdline of a running process?

Answer (score 4):

Although probably noone is going to use VMWare Server any more, this problem would arise with other processes as well. You really *should* look at [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/) instead, it allows for side-scrolling to read the entire command line and displays process trees:

[image: http://htop.sourceforge.net/htop-1.0-screenshot.png]

As for your question, changing the command line of a process which is runnnig already is likely to be possible only by overwriting data at the memory address of its ARGV[0]. To my knowledge, no tool is yet available which just would do `changecmdline 4652 "foo process"`. Further discussion: http://stupefydeveloper.blogspot.de/2008/10/linux-change-process-name.html

Answer (score 3):

How about the following:

`watch 'ps -eo pid,pcpu,args | grep vmware'`

Watch will run the command every 2 seconds. `pcpu` is cpu percentage.

Comment: This is pretty close. I could probably combine this with sed to show exactly what I want. If nobody else provides the exact answer I'm looking for, I'll assume it can't be done and will probably accept this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed an annoying problem.

The real solution is posted here:

http://blog.angulosolido.pt/2012/01/vmware-2-long-process-names-and-top.html

The script is NOT pretty but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, I don't think it is possible without recompiling the kernel. I've checked top and it's definitely pulling it from /proc:
`strace top -c 2>&1 | grep "proc"

open("/proc/6501/stat", O_RDONLY)       = 4

open("/proc/6501/statm", O_RDONLY)      = 4

open("/proc/6501/cmdline", O_RDONLY)    = 4`

As you say, /proc/pid/cmdline is not writeable by root. Have you considered running them with a wrapper program? eg. bash script ./vmware that just executes
`/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-vmx -# product=2;name=VMware Server;version=2.0.2;buildnumber=203138;licensename=VMware GSX Server for Linux;licenseversion=3.0 build-203138; -@ pipe=/tmp/vmhsdaemon-0/vmxaf9a31943e9065f0;readyEvent=55 $1"`

It's worth noting that top only truncates when it's out of space. Why not open top, hit f and remove any fields you're not using. You might just find it leaves enough space for the entire cmdline

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but perhaps an answer to your problem:

1. Use LSOF to find out which PIDs are using which VMDKs
2. Use ps and grep for those PIDs

This could be easily scripted, I don't have a Linux console opened right now though. Exercise left for the reader.

Comment: True, I could script that. I'm basically using ps and grep right now -- finding the top orocess, switching screens, `ps awwwx | grep $pid`, and this gives me the VMX name, it's just tedious!

Comment: Yeah, script it from the other side.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

DELAY=2
DIRNAME=virtual

while true; do
    clear; ps -eo pid,pcpu,args | grep vmx|grep $DIRNAME  |awk '{ print $1 " " $2 " " $NF}'| sort -rn -k 2; sleep $DELAY;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
A=`ps -e -o pid,cmd| grep vmware-vmx | grep -v match | awk 'BEGIN {print "{" } {gsub(/^.*\//, "", $NF); print "if (match($0, / *" $1 " /)) { sub(\"vmware-vmx          \",\"" "%-20s" "\",$0); printf($0,\"" $NF "\"); print \"\";} else "} END {print "print $0 }"}'`
top | awk "$A"
```

The script works as a filter to TOP output and replaces "vmware-vmx" with VM name. It assumes .vmx file is no more than 20 chars. This is because you have to preserve the line size generated by top.